# How to prove the homogeneous Sobolev spaces $\dot{W}^{1,p}$ on cubes are equivalent to the Sobolev spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $1\leqslant p<\infty$, $Q\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ a cube. Define the homogeneous Sobolev space:
$$ \dot{W}^{1,p}(Q)=\{u\in L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}(Q): D^\alpha u\in L^p(Q), |\alpha|=1\}.$$
Prove that $\forall u\in \dot{W}^{1,p}(Q)$,  $u\in W^{1,p}(Q)$.

I know if $u\in \dot{W}^{1,p}(Q)$, then $u\in L^p_{\mathrm{loc}}(Q)$, hence $\forall \tilde{Q}\subset\subset Q$, we get $u\in W^{1,p}(\tilde{Q})$, where "$\subset\subset$" means $\tilde{Q}$ is open, the closure of $\tilde{Q}$ is compact and contained in $Q$. I don't know what to do next. This is the variant of Exercise 13.35 come from A First Course in Sobolev Spaces, 2nd written by Giovanni Leoni.  This exercise is given behind Poincare's inequality for rectangles, but I don't know how to use this proposition. [image]

And I also want to know whether this claim is true or not for $p=\infty$.

Comment: By Sobolev's embedding the function is in $L^q$ for some $q>p$, and so in $L^p$

Answer (score 1):

Let $T\Subset S\Subset R$. Then $u\in W^{1,p}(S)$. By the fundamental theorem
of calculus, for all $x\in S$ and $y\in T$,
\begin{align*}
|u(x)-u(y)| &  \leq|u(x)-u(x_{1},\ldots,x_{N-1},y_{N})|\\
&  \quad+\cdots+|u(x_{1},y_{2},\ldots,y_{N})-u(y)|\\
&  \leq\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{0}^{a_{i}}|\partial_{i}u(x_{1},\ldots
,x_{i-1},t,y_{i+1},\ldots,y_{N})|\,dt.
\end{align*}
Raising both sides to power $p$, by H"{o}lder's inequality, and the convexity
of the function $g(t)=|t|^{p}$,
\begin{align*}
|u &  (x)-u(y)|^{p}\leq\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^{N}\Bigl(\int_{0}^{a_{i}}
|\partial_{i}u(x_{1},\ldots,x_{i-1},t,y_{i+1},\ldots,y_{N})|^{p}
dt\Bigr)^{\frac{1}{p}}\biggr)^{p}\\
&  \leq N^{p-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{0}^{a_{i}}|\partial_{i}u(x_{1}
,\ldots,x_{i-1},t,y_{i+1},\ldots,y_{N})|^{p}dt.
\end{align*}
Hence, again by H"{o}lder's inequality and the fact that $u(x)-u_{T}
=(u(x)-u)_{T}$,
\begin{align*}
\int_{S} &  |u(x)-u_{T}|^{p}\,dx\leq\frac{1}{(\mathcal{L}^{N}(T))^{p}}\int
_{S}\Bigl(\int_{T}|u(x)-u(y)|\,dy\Bigr)^{p}dx\\
&  \leq\frac{1}{(\mathcal{L}^{N}(T))^{p-p/p^{\prime}}}\int_{S}\int
_{T}|u(x)-u(y)|^{p}dydx\\
&  \leq\frac{N^{p-1}}{\mathcal{L}^{N}(T)}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{S}\int_{T}
\int_{0}^{a_{i}}|\partial_{i}u(x_{1},\ldots,x_{i-1},t,y_{i+1},\ldots
,y_{N})|^{p}dtdydx\\
&  \leq\frac{N^{p-1}\mathcal{L}^{N}(R)}{\mathcal{L}^{N}(T)}\sum_{i=1}^{N}
a_{i}\int_{R}|\partial_{i}u(z)|^{p}dz\leq\frac{N^{p-1}\mathcal{L}^{N}
(R)}{\mathcal{L}^{N}(T)}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{R}|\partial_{i}u(z)|^{p}dz,
\end{align*}
where we have used the facts that $p-p/p^{\prime}=1$, $\max\{a_{1}
,\ldots,a_{N}\}=1$, and Fubini's theorem.

If you now take an increasing sequence $S_{n}$ containing $T$ and whose union
is $R$, replacing $S$ with $S_{n}$ and using the Lebesgue monotone convergence
theorem on the left-hand side gives
$$
\int_{R}|u(x)-u_{T}|^{p}\,dx\leq\frac{N^{p-1}\mathcal{L}^{N}(R)}
{\mathcal{L}^{N}(T)}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{R}|\partial_{i}u(z)|^{p}dz,
$$